# Distortion after applying not proportional scaling and rotation on a view using CGAffineTransform

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgaffinetransform, cgaffinetransformscale

So I need to apply scaling and rotation to a view. When perform proportional "x" / "y" scale and then "rotate" view - all looks fine, but when apply not proportional "x", "y" scale and rotate - view distorted
[example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jdv61yfus505ql0/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202015-04-04%2015.57.52.png?dl=0)

to perform transformations use CGAffineTransformRotate, CGAffineTransformScale.

I have no idea how to apply rotation to scaled(not proportional) view without distortion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because geometric transformations using matrices are (generally) [not commutative](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/geometry/geo-tran.html), i.e. the order in which the transformations are applied does matter.

To get what you want, first apply the scaling and then rotate the scaled image.

Comment: it work! Thank you!

self.object.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformMakeScale(xScale, yScale), CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle));